# How to get the overlaps effect when the width is reduce?

Tags: html, css

I imitate a website: https://open.weixin.qq.com/

You see the overlaps is my requirement, if I reduce the width of browser.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

But in my project when I reduce the browser width, I will get the this irksome effect:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

---

My code is bellow, the images can not shows up but this is not the point:

```css
.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 68px;
    background-color: #363636;
  }

  .container {
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-right: 40px;
  }

  .container > div {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .logo {
    height: 100%;
    width: 240px;
  }

  .logo img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  .nav {
    display: inline-block;

  }

  .nav li {
    width: 96px;
    height: 100%;
    color: #afafaf;
    line-height: 68px;
    float: left;
  }

  .nav li :hover {
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .nav .selected {
    color: #fff;
  }

  .right-buttons {
    float: right;
  }

  .login-logout {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 68px;
    color: #ffffff;
    line-height: 68px;
  }

  .qrcode {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 68px;
    height: 68px;
    align-content: center;
    line-height: 68px;
  }

  .qrcode img {
    line-height: 68px;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="../../assets/img/common/logo.png">
      </div>
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="nav-item selected">首页</li>
        <li class="nav-item">数据中心</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="right-buttons">
        <div class="login-logout">
          <button>登录/注册</button>
        </div>
        <div class="qrcode">
          <img src="../../assets/img/home/little-qrcode.png">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

How can I get the upper effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood, you need right-buttons div overlapped to nav ul instead of going to next line.

Apply "position:absolute" and "right: 0" to right-buttons instead of "float: right".

But in smaller widths, overlapping will confuse the user. So its better you make it responsive for all devices.